# Keyboard freezes after pressing caps lock

Tags: keyboard, performance, caps-lock

After running for a day or two (not right after booting it), my laptop begins to display a strange behaviour: after pressing the caps lock my keyboard freezes which means that it does not respond to any input, however, if you press the caps lock with another character, e.g. "X", it continues to press "X" indefinitely. The only thing that can help is a restart. I've attached my laptop specs below, other than that I'm not sure what information could be useful in debugging this, so please let me know if you have any clues. If I check the crash report, the only thing that appears in there is OneDrive crashing about the same time I experienced the issue.

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: this looks like a hardware problem, and you might want to see if you can run hardware diagnostic: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: @user1256923 thank you for the suggestion, I ran the diagnostics tool and it couldn't detect any issues.

Comment: Try an external keyboard (doesn't have to be from Apple) and see if that works ok.

Comment: Same issue for me, and it happens with different keyboards

Answer (score 2):

For me resetting the NVRAM fixed it:

1. Shut down your Mac and start it again.
2. Hold Option, Command, P, and R keys.
3. Keep the keys pressed until:

- You hear the startup sound playing for a second time – on non-T2 models
- You see the Apple logo appear and disappear for the second time – on T2 models

From: https://windowsreport.com/mac/macbook-stuck-caps-lock/

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that my problem was caused by the Karabiner software (alters the layout of your keyboard). I disabled the caps entirely and the issue disappeared.